# Equivalent Resistance between A and B

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, resistance

I am having difficulties finding the equivalent resistance between points A and B. While a solution is appreciated, I'm rather looking for an explanation/redrawing and understanding of the circuit. Thank you.
[image: Circuit]

Comment: I will be honest with you. I would enter it in a simulator and let the simulator figure it out. Don't judge me. Otherwise, I think you might be able to use super-position. Apply 1V, and figure out total current using superposition.

Comment: Have a think about all the possible current paths between A and B. See what resistors each path would encounter.

Comment: @mkeith +1 because simulation is exactly how to solve this in the real world. -1 because superposition is a method for solving circuits with multiple sources, which isn't applicable here.

Comment: Yeah. Superposition means keeping 1 source (either current or voltage) at a time while shortcircuiting the rest of the voltage sources or leaving an open circuit for the current sources and solving the currents. Not applicable here indeed

Comment: Good thing I didn't write it as an answer. I might have lost rep. What I was thinking of in my head was applying a test voltage, and working out the total current one branch at a time. Not really super-position. Mea Culpa.

Comment: Please use the schematic editor when you post a question like this. Sure, you have to spend some time learning how to use it. Sure, you have to spend some time putting the schematic in. What you did do was probably take the path offering the least possible effort from you. That isn't fair to any of us. It's your question and you should apply yourself to allowing us to spend the least amount of time helping ***you***. Not the other way around. Had you used the schematic editor, we'd have labels on the resistors and that would make communication much easier and faster for us.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please take @jonk advice and label your parts next time. You already have valid answers so too late for this one, as they have moved on to other questions. Or you can use this one for practice. It makes no difference now.

Comment: You can actually use superposition to solve this. Just a little imagination needed; imagine that the voltage source connected to R2 has the same voltage as the source connected to R4 - yes they might as well be joined, but for super-position you can treat them as two (but identical) votlage sources and ground each one in turn. @mkeith - take note - you can do it with superposition! Circuit references as per BeB00's answer.

Comment: C_Elegans has the most straightforward and elegant solution. Being able to spot and use delta-wye will help you in all sorts of situations. It works for all impedances as well, not just resistors.

Comment: @jonk I apologize and I hope you realize that was never my intention as even in my question I was not looking just for the answer, but rather to have a discussion on how to solve this type of exercise. I had no idea that type of feature is available on this website, and the exercise you see is exactly how I found it. I will definitely keep in mind your advice for the next time, thanks!

Comment: @user2342352 Just "tossing out a question" doesn't recognize well the effort you stimulate in others who then read (or try to read) what you write. You spend a few minutes composing something that will readily eat up a man-hour of the time of others within the first minutes of posting it. And if you get answers, those trying will now have to do the work you didn't do in order to just begin to help out. It's considerate of the time of others to spend your own time, so that you've done your best before asking for the time of others. It's polite. You missed something. I reminded you, is all.

Answer (score 4):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fg2m4k.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

From this rearrangement, you can see that there are 4 nodes. One way to solve this is nodal analysis. You put a unit current source between a and b, and set B to 0, giving you three node equations:

$$A:\frac{(V_A-V_3)}{2}+\frac{(V_A-V_4)}{1}+\frac{(V_A-0)}{5}-1=0$$

$$3: \frac{(V_3-V_A)}{2}+\frac{(V_3-V_4)}{2}+\frac{(V_3-0)}{3}=0$$

$$4: \frac{(V_4-V_A)}{1}+\frac{(V_4-V_3)}{2}+\frac{(V_4-0)}{4}=0$$

You then solve for A to get the voltage. Since you know the current going into the system (1 Amp), you can use:

$$\frac{V}{I}=R$$

Since I=1, the resistance will actually just be the voltage at A.

Comment: All of that to get a 1 ohm resistor...

Comment: Thank you! I was actually trying to solve for Thevenin resistance. In the problem there are 2 voltage sources which I have shortcircuited already. This configuration gave me some serious headaches. I will study your response and see if I can figure it out on my own

Comment: I think you swapped the order of R5 and R4. I put the circuit in the simulator and got .610A for the current, which gives 1.64 ohms for the resistance

Comment: @C_Elegans are you talking about my answer? or replying to sparky?

Comment: @BeB00 I’m talking about your answer, I think you swapped r4 and r5. I wish I’d drawn it the way you did when I tried to solve it, yours makes more sense than mine

Comment: @C_Elegans no, you can tell it's the correct way round because of the nodes theyre each connected to. The 1Ohm is connected between A and the 4-2 Ohms, and the 4Ohm is connected between B and the 1-2 Ohms. The same is true in my diagram, so they must be in the correct positions.

Answer (score 1):

This hasn't a trivial solution which uses the common serial and parallel connection formulas. General circuit analysis methods must be used. An example which has only 2 unknowns to be solved:

Let node A to be your GND. Input voltage +1V to node B (minus to GND)

Unknown 1 = V1 = voltage of the joint of 1 Ohm and 4 Ohm resistors

Unknown 2 = V2 = voltage of the joint of 2 Ohm and 3 Ohm resistors.

Write normal nodal voltage analysis equations for V1 and V2 and solve them.

Calculate voltages over 3 and 4 Ohm resistors. (= one volt - V1 and one volt - V2)

Calculate the currents through 3,4 and 5 Ohm resistors.

Get the sum (=I) of the currents

Calculate the total resistance = 1V/I

Answer (score 1):

The main thing here is to use [delta-wye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform) conversions to transform the resistors into a shape that can be analyzed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4xt9L.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Notice the ∏ shape formed by R3, R7, and R8. This can be transformed to a delta shape by using \$Ra = \frac{R7*R3}{R3+R7+R8}\$, \$Rb = \frac{R8*R3}{R3+R7+R8}\$, and \$Rc = \frac{R7*R8}{R3+R7+R8}\$. This gives you:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBGyIz.png)</sup>

Next, combine the series resistors R6 and Rc, giving:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmhF4X.png)</sup>

Figuring out the resistance should be fairly straightforward from here, yielding a final resistance of \$1.64\Omega\$

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this type of circuits is to apply the [FACTs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1119236371) and, in this particular case, the extra-element theorem or [EET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra_element_theorem) forged by Dr. Middlebrook. The key to solving this type of exercise is to simplify and reorganize the circuit as correctly suggested by BeB00. A quick sim with a 1-A dc current source and a dc bias calculation shows the resistance value we want and obtained from both schematics: \$R_{AB}=1.639\;\Omega\$.

[image]

Now, to determine this value swiftly without effort but also without writing a single line of algebra, you can realize that \$R_1\$ is in || with the resistance you want from terminals A and B. Therefore, you can temporarily remove this resistance and will later place it back in || with the expression obtained without it to form the final result. This is the first step. Then, to determine the transfer function - because an impedance or here a resistance is a transfer function liking a response to a stimulus - I will install a current source \$I_T\$ (the stimulus) forcing a voltage response across its terminals, \$V_T\$. Obviously, the ratio of \$V_T\$ by \$I_T\$ is the resistance we want:

[image]

Then, to apply the EET, we have to identify an element whose presence troubles us to determine the transfer function. To me, it's \$R_6\$ and I select it as the extra element (you could select any component). I then have the choice to either replace it by a short circuit or open circuit it to calculate the *reference value*, \$R_{ref}\$. I choose to calculate the reference value when \$R_6\$ is open circuited. Redraw the circuit without \$R_1\$ and, in your head, what resistance do you "see" from the left-side connecting points?

[image]

You see - like if you would connect an ohm-meter in your head - the series-parallel combination of the resistors: \$R_{ref}=(R_2+R_3)||(R_4+R_5)\$.

Now, to apply the EET, you have to turn the excitation off. The excitation in this resistance determination exercise is the current source. Turn it to 0 A or open-circuit it. What resistance \$R_d\$ do you "see" between \$R_6\$ connecting terminals? \$R_d=(R_2+R_4)||(R_3+R_5)\$.

Then, you have to null the response in order to determine \$R_n\$. Nulling the response means that despite a current generator \$I_T\$ placed across \$R_6\$ terminals, the response (the voltage \$V_T\$ between A and B) is 0 V. A 0-V condition across a current source is a degenerate case and the current source can be replaced by a short circuit. Now, if you update the schematic as below in which the current source is shorted, what resistance \$R_n\$ do you "see" between \$R_6\$ connecting terminals? \$R_n=(R_2||R_3)+(R_4||R_5)\$.

[image]

This is it, it's done! Apply the EET formula as follows

\$R_{AB}=R_1||(R_{ref}\frac{1+\frac{R_n}{R_6}}{1+\frac{R_d}{R_6}})=R_1 || ((R_2+R_3)||(R_4+R_5)\times\frac{1+\frac{(R_2||R_3)+(R_4||R_5)}{R_6}}{1+\frac{(R_2+R_4)||(R_3+R_5)}{R_6}}))\$

and if you capture the formula in Mathcad, you have the exact value as given by SPICE:

[image]

I do not expect you to master the technique overnight but you can see how appealing these FACTs are: you can solve by inspection very often (no algebra) and you can individually correct the intermediate steps in case you identify a mistake. Really cool and I encourage EE students to acquire this skill which dates back to H. Bode book from 1945 : ) It is of invaluable help to determine transfer functions of any order. A tutorial on FACTs is available [here](http://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202016.pdf).

Comment: Much appreciated! Will definitely have a look into it